# Can't rake build. Stack trace points to ruby_executable_hooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, build, rake, precompile

I'm not sure when this happened, but I've gotten my environment into a state where I can't rake build. I looked at the stack trace, but nothing in it is helpful for me.

```
$ bundle exec rake build --trace
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'build' (see --tasks)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:71:in `[]'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It's looks like you have no defined rake task `build` in the directory you are calling from. Try `rake -T` to see a list of defined rake tasks.

Comment: @Joseph so yeah it looks like you're right. I didn't see "build" in that list. What does that mean though? Is something wrong?

Comment: what are you trying to build?

Comment: I was having some issues with precompiling JS files and thought a rake build might help. More generally speaking, I thought that rake build was the sort of command you could run at any time to build your app, regardless of if it currently needs building.

Comment: some gems and frameworks may come with a `rake build` task, but it only exists if it is defined (e.g., in the `Rakefile`). What are you trying to do? Are you working on a Rails app?

Comment: @Joseph, well like I said in my other comment, I was having some issues with precompiling JS files and thought maybe a rake build would fix it. It didn't surprise me that it didn't work, but I was under the impression that rake build was something you were supposed to be able to do at any time to build your app. I thought that the fact I couldn't meant I must have mucked up my config or something. If that's not the case, then maybe there's no issue.

Comment: Yeah, `build` is just a common name people use for a rake task. It's not required and it doesn't come pre-built (so to speak) with Rake. I don't think Rails has a task called `build`.

Comment: you can precompile your whole asset pipeline, and run trace against that to find the errors -- RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile